# Casting variables in R Power BI scripts

Tags: sql-server, r, powerbi

How I can cast variables in R scripts in Power BI? I get:

> ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class integer

I cannot check class of these variables:

```
class(dataset$Transaction)
```

because I get:

> Error Message: No image was created. The R code did not result in
>   creation of any visuals. Make sure your R script results in a plot to
>   the R default device.